# Display the number of times each output was displayed in 'X's

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
while True:
    try:
        wins = int(input("enter number of wins: "))                
        draws = int(input("enter number of draws: "))
        losses = int(input("enter number of losses: "))
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
        continue

    if wins>3:
        print('qualify')
    elif losses>3:
       print('disqualify')
   elif draws>3:
       print('try again')

   restart = str(input('enter "restart" to restart or "quit" to quit'))
   if restart == 'restart':
       continue
   elif restart == 'quit':
       #quit and display number of occurrences of qualify, disqualify and try again in 'X's
```

Comment: this is my 1st time using stack overflow mind this mess

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- we are not going to test it for you.  You've shown no output, no error, no question.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question but based on what I understood I constructed a solution. This will show you the result of occurrence of qualify and disqualify

```
qualifycount=0
disqualifycount=0
while True:
    try:
        wins = int(input("enter number of wins: "))                
        draws = int(input("enter number of draws: "))
        losses = int(input("enter number of losses: "))
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
        continue

    if wins>3:
        print('qualify')
        qualifycount+=1
    elif losses>3:
       print('disqualify')
       disqualifycount+=1
    elif draws>3:
       print('try again')
   
    restart = str(input('enter "restart" to restart or "quit" to quit'))
    if restart == 'restart':
       continue
    elif restart == 'quit':
       #quit and display number of occurrences of qualify, disqualify and try again in 'X's
       print("Number of qualify:"+str(qualifycount))
       print("Number of disqualify:"+str(disqualifycount))
       restart= str(input('press X to run again or press enter to quit'))
       if restart=='X':
           continue
       else:
           break
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to track the count of each result.  You could do this with three different variables, but I think it's a little easier to use a dictionary, or better yet a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
```

Make sure to initialize this *outside* your loop, since you want to keep the same Counter through multiple iterations of the loop; if you reset it inside the loop, it won't keep track of anything!

Then track the results as you see them:

```
    if wins > 3:
        result = "qualify"
    elif losses > 3:
        result = "disqualify"
    elif draws > 3:
        result = "try again"
    else:
        print("Not enough of anything to produce a result!")
        continue
    print(result)
    counts[result] += 1
```

and then at the end, you can convert the counts into "X" marks by string multiplication:

```
for result in counts:
    print(f"{result}: {'X' * counts[result]}")
```

All together it looks like:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
while True:
    try:
        wins = int(input("enter number of wins: "))                
        draws = int(input("enter number of draws: "))
        losses = int(input("enter number of losses: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("try again")
        continue

    if wins > 3:
        result = "qualify"
    elif losses > 3:
        result = "disqualify"
    elif draws > 3:
        result = "try again"
    else:
        print("Not enough of anything to produce a result!")
        continue
    print(result)
    counts[result] += 1

    if str(input('enter "restart" to restart or "quit" to quit')) == "quit":
        break

for result in counts:
    print(f"{result}: {'X' * counts[result]}")
```